# can not be assigned to a variable error in eclipse (homework)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am building on a ordering program for java for a class in school and I am getting quantityInput can not be resolved to a variable error I also get the error

> the method `showInputDialog(Component, Object, Object)` in the type `JOptionPane` is not applicable for the arguments `(String, int, int)`

any help in resolving the 2 errors would be much aprecated.

```
/**
 * Course:   IT110 - Introduction to Programming
 * Filename: KagesKreationsPhase1.java
 * Created:  04/09/10 by Dr. Debby Telfer
 * Modified: 11/26/13 by Dr. Bary W Pollack
 * 
 * Purpose:  Created a simple online ordering system
 *           for Pizzas-R-Us customers
 */

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * @author bary
 */
public class KagesKreations {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // declare variables
        String openingMsg, nameInputMsg, customerName, nameOutputMsg,   getReturning, getColor, getQuantity,
               returnInputMsg, customerReturn, returnOutputMsg, quantityMsg, quantityOutputMsg, totalOutputMsg,
               colorChoiceMsg, colorChoice, colorChoiceOutputMsg, greetingOutputMsg, outputMsg, quantityInput, getname;

        int number = 0;
        double cost = 10.00;
        double taxRate = 1.07;
        double total;


        try {

            // display opening message
            openingMsg = "*** Welcome to Kage's Kreations Online Ordering System ***\n"
                   + "                     Lets Pick A Kustiom Kreation!";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, openingMsg);

            // get required input using dialogs
            customerName   = getName();
            customerReturn = getReturning();
            colorChoice    = getColor();
            quantityInput  = getQuantity();
            number = Integer.parseInt(quantityInput);

            KagesKreations.totalCost(number, cost, taxRate);

            total = totalCost(number, cost, taxRate);

            writeOrderFile(customerName, customerReturn, colorChoice,quantityInput, total);
            confirmation();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

    } // end main()
    public static String getStringInput(String prompt) throws Exception {
        String value;
        int i = 0;
        do {

            value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);i++;

            if (value == null) {
                throw new Exception("Cancle was pressed. Closeing the program.");

            }
        } while (value.equals("") && i < 3); 
           if (value.equals("")) {
               throw new Exception("No input vale was entered after three attempts.");

           }
            return value;
    }


    public static int getQuantity(int lowValue, int highValue) throws Exception {
        // quantity must be between 1-99
        int quantity;
        int counter = 0;
        int quantityInput;

        do {
            quantityInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many bracelets would you like to order? (1-99)", 1, 99));
            counter = counter + 1;
            } while (quantityInput < lowValue || quantityInput > highValue && counter < 3);
        if (quantityInput < lowValue || quantityInput > highValue) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid responce please enter a number between 1 and 99");

        }


        quantity = quantityInput;
        return quantity;
    }

    public static String getColor() throws Exception {
    String color;
    int counter = 0;
    do {
        color = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose Brown or Black for the color of your bracelet");
        counter = counter + 1;
        } while (!color.equals("Brown") && !color.equals("Black") && counter < 3);

        if (!color.equals("Brown") && !color.equals("Black")) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid responce please enter Brown or Black.");
            }
        return color;
    }

    public static String getReturning() throws Exception {
        String returning;
        int counter = 0;
        do {
            returning = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you a returning customer? (Yes or No)");
            counter = counter +1;

            } while (!returning.equals("Yes") && !returning.equals("No") && counter < 3 );

        if (!returning.equals("Yes") && !returning.equals("No")) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid responce please enter Yes or No.");
            }

        return returning;
    }

    public static String getName() throws Exception {
        String name;
        int counter = 0;

        do {
            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter your name.");
            counter = counter + 1;
        } while (counter < 3);
    return name;

    }

    public static double totalCost(int number, double cost, double taxRate){
        double total = 0;
        total = (number * cost) * taxRate;

        return total;
    }

    public static void writeOrderFile(String name, String returning, String color, String quantity, double total) throws Exception {
        File order = new File("order.tx");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(order);
        pw.println(name);
        pw.println(returning);
        pw.println(color);
        pw.println(quantity);
        pw.println(total);
        pw.close();
    }

    public static void confirmation() throws Exception{
        String nameOutputMsg, customerName, returnOutputMsg, customerReturn, colorChoiceOutputMsg, colorChoice, quantityOutputMsg, quantityInput,
               totalOutputMsg, total, greetingOutputMsg, outputMsg;

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("order.txt");
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
        customerName = bf.readLine();
        customerReturn = bf.readLine();
        colorChoice = bf.readLine();
        quantityInput = bf.readLine();
        total = bf.readLine();

        fr.close();
        // build output strings
                    nameOutputMsg     = "Welcome " + customerName + ".\n\n";
                    returnOutputMsg   = "Your return customer status is " + customerReturn + ".\n";
                    colorChoiceOutputMsg = "You have chosen " + colorChoice + " as the color for your braclet.\n";
                    quantityOutputMsg = "You have ordered " + quantityInput + " bracelets.\n";
                    totalOutputMsg = "Your total cost is $" + total + ".\n";
                    greetingOutputMsg = "Thank you for visiting Kage's Kreations!" + "\n\n"
                                  + "Your order should ships in 24 to 48 hours.\n";


                    // create and display output string
                    outputMsg = nameOutputMsg + returnOutputMsg + colorChoiceOutputMsg + quantityOutputMsg + totalOutputMsg + greetingOutputMsg;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputMsg);

    }

} // end class KagesKreationsPhase1
```

Comment: `can not be resolved to a variable` means that variable is not declared.

Comment: **Where** do you declare the quantityInput variable?

Comment: I see now that I did not declare it so that fixed one error but I still can not fix  the error the method showInputDialog(Component, Object, Object) in the type JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int)

Comment: changed the post to show the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second prolem is that [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-) just does not provide any method that matches the arguments you try to pass in your `getQuantity`-mehod:

```
quantityInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many bracelets would you like to order? (1-99)", 1, 99));
```

You have to chose one of the existing methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a variable before using it. You can declare the variable inside the getQuantity() or in class level (Please read much about local and class variables). you can declare it as the way you declared quantity and counter variables.

```
  public static int getQuantity(int lowValue, int highValue) throws Exception {
        // quantity must be between 1-99
        int quantity;
        int counter = 0;
        int quantityInput = 0;
    ...
    }
```

In your code I can't find a place where you are using showInputDialog() with String, int, int parameters. Please share the full code your trying.

Comment: Instead JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many bracelets would you like to order? (1-99)", 1, 99) ,Please use "JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many bracelets would you like to order? The number of bracelets should between 1-99")" since you request input from parameter. There is  no method in JOption showInputDialog() which expects String,int,int. You can refer [1] to and search for showInputDialog in Method Summary area to find the parameters that you can use with showInputDialog()